# Making a script to replace characters in selected string on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I wanted to make a script on Ubuntu that I am going to use to convert selected cyrillic string into latin using keyboard shortcut while editing some text files. For example,

```
Selected string | Changed 

қызыл           | qızıl
```

Can you help me to do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing a certain operation on Ubuntu and might be better suited to http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I asked there first, then some "smart" people sent me here

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with the "translation" and then do the replacement with `sed i`:

```
declare -A array=()

while read word trans;
do
        array[$word]="$trans"
done < your_list

file="file_to_replace"
for key in ${!array[@]}; do
    #echo "array[$key] = ${array[$key]}" # to see the array composition
    sed -i "s/$key/${array[$key]}/g" $file
done
```

This supposes that `your_list` contains two columns. First with the word and second with the "translation".

Then `sed -i` performs an in-place substitution with the `sed s/something/replacement/g` syntax.